# Processing unix paths in Windows

Tags: java, nio, filepath

What's the best way of processing *ix file path strings when running on Windows?

If I just use `Paths.get()` it invokes `Filesystem.getDefault()` which ends up processing it like a Windows path. The parsing *seems* to work in my tests but they're pretty rudimentary, and of course `toString` uses the wrong path separator.

Can I manually load up the LinuxFileSystem somehow? Or should I use the `commons-io` parser instead?

Comment: I believe that all Windows systems since Windows 2000 accept `/` as well as `'\'` as the file separator character, in their API's.  So most likely you don't need to do anything, as long as everything on Windows will be on the same drive.  If this doesn't work, please provide an example of what doesn't work and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Like I said it does parse in my basic tests, but the output is uses the wrong path separator. I suspect the windows parser might have some issues with backslashes which are legal in *ix path names.

Comment: I doubt it, because one JDK distribution is oriented either to Unix or either to Windows. The only chance I think of is that you look for an opensource distribution of some UnixFileSystemProvider and import into your application's runtime. And even in that case, I have my doubts, because UnixFileSystemProvider deals with low-level details from the underlying OS - not just path separators.

Comment: @LittleSanti: The answer is yours by rights.  Please claim it if you want the points!

Comment: @Downvoter: Why the downvote?  What didn't you understand?

Comment: @Ian Thanks. I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I manually load up the LinuxFileSystem somehow?

I doubt it, because one JDK distribution is oriented either to Unix or either to Windows. The only chance I think of is that you look for an open source distribution of some UnixFileSystemProvider and import into your application's runtime.

But even in that case, I have my doubts it will work 100%, because a FileSystemProvider class deals with low-level details from the underlying OS - not just path separators, so there is a risk that it won't be compatible over a Windows filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like @Little Santi's comment on the question is in fact the answer.  If I run:

```
for (FileSystemProvider provider: FileSystemProvider.installedProviders()) {
  System.out.println(provider.getClass().getName());
}
```

I get:

```
sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider
com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider
```

If I interpret this correctly it means I can't use the LinuxFileSystem path methods under Windows but should use commons-io instead.